# Return to calling page iText

Tags: itext

I've created a pdf document using iText which catalogues my music collection grouped by artist, I've used an example from the book iText in Action to create a TOC which sets up links to jump to the selected chapter. All is working as expected. What I would like to add on every chapter is a link to return to the page in the TOC that I was in prior to clicking on the link. I can't see anything in the book which explains how to do this.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You say that you could create links to specific pages (where every chapter starts) thanks to what is explained by my book. At the same time you claim that my book doesn't explain how to create links to a specific page (where the TOC starts). That doesn't make sense does it? Either my book explains how to create links to specific pages or it doesn't. I know it does and I know you know,  otherwise you couldn't create the links to the pages where each chapter starts. What is so different about creating a link to the page where the TOC starts?

Comment: Sorry Bruno I probably haven't described my problem very well, I create my TOC which could be several pages long, I browse to a page in the TOC ( for arguments sake let's say page 4 ) . I click on a link and arrive on a page ( let's say page 99 ) How do I now navigate back to page 4 ?

Comment: I still don't understand. You say that you can create a link from page 4 to page 99, but that you don't manage to create a link from page 99 to page 4? Why don't you store information about the TOC while creating it? That way you know which page to link to. Another option would be to create a named destination for every entry in the TOC (but that sounds like overkill).

Comment: Sorry Bruno I was being dumb - that's what I've done now thanks very much - sometimes I can't see the wood for the trees